# Regular Language (yes or no)

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata

I was given the task to check whether this language is regular:

```
L = {w∈{a,b,c}* | where the number of a is less than the number of b+c.}
```

I can find neither a regular expression for this, nor a deterministic (or not) finite state automaton.
On the other hand, I did not find any way to prove the opposite with the pumping lemma theorem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking it isn't, but i haven't taken enough CS to say for sure why.  Something to do with the legality of `a` depending not on what follows or precedes it, but on whether there are enough `b`s or `c`s throughout the string.  That's not regular.  I'm not sure if it's even context-free.

Comment: I believe that `E` in the equation above should be replaced with `∈`.

Comment: It is kinda looking like it, from the googling i've been doing.  :)  Oh, and it appears the language is at least context-free, though i can't seem to make it regular.

Answer (score 3):

### Disclaimer

I know that a formal proof using the pumping lemma has been posted above. However, I'll go for a completely informal explanation, because I believe it usually helps having some intuition about the problem before going for a formal solution.

### General intuition

In general, when a language depends on some sort of counting, it should ring a bell that it is probably not regular. The reason is that *counting can get arbitrarily large*. You can see this concretely in your example.

### Why is it not regular?

Imagine trying to create a DFS for your language. What you care about is the difference between the number of `a` and the sum of the number of `b` and `c` (call this `D_abc`). *In a DFS, all information is captured in the state itself*. As an example, consider the state after reading 10 consecutive `a` and the one after reading 100 consecutive `a`. These two states *have* to be different. Now, extending this argument for any number of `a` (or equivalently any `D_abc`) you can conclude that you need an infinite number of states, i.e. the language is *not regular*.

### Bonus: Why is it context-free?

Now, think about using a pushdown automaton. The PDA allows you to capture the difficulty of (infinite) counting by using its (infinite) stack. In your example, you can do it like this:

- If the stack is empty (i.e. `D_abc = 0`), push whatever symbol you encounter onto the stack (i.e. if an `a` comes along `D_abc <- 1`, else if a `b` or `c` comes along `D_abc <- -1`).
- If the top element of the stack is `a` (i.e. `D_abc` > 0), if an `a` comes along push it onto the stack (i.e. `D_abc <- D_abc + 1`, else pop the top `a` from the stack (i.e. `D_abc <- D_abc - 1`).
- Similarly, if the top element is `b` or `c` (i.e. `D_abc < 0`), if a `b` or `c` comes along push it onto the stack (i.e. `D_abc <- D_abc - 1`), else remove the top element from the stack (i.e. `D_abc <- D_abc + 1`).

Using the above rules, the stack keeps count of `D_abc` at each moment, which is exactly what you need to accept or not accept a string. Thus, you can conclude that the language is *context-free*.